# How to arrange cards vertically into two columns

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I need to arrange following set of cards into two columns and appear vertically after one by one. SO that I can arrange then in a order in mobile devices.

[image]

I have used flex layout to create this but it doesn't help when the cards had different heights.

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui segment">About</div>
  <div class="ui segment">Video</div>
  <div class="ui segment">Experiences</div>
  <div class="ui segment">Preferences</div>
  <div class="ui segment">Skills</div>
  <div class="ui segment">Education</div>
  <div class="ui segment">Projects</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/WenukaGTX/pen/YoeMZL) for this.

Mobile design would be like this.

[image]

Comment: @Paulie_D It's for the layouts which has one card in the left column. In my case I cannot make left side card height 100%. I need every card to arrange one after one into two columns.

Comment: Issue is the same - it's not possible at present without additional wrappers and `display:contents` which has little support. CSS-Grid can't help as it's clearly *not a grid*.

Comment: @Paulie_D I suggest that this not a duplicated question. This is a unique requirement.

Comment: The *basic* issue is a duplicate as I have already stated. This is not possible with your given structure. - check the other link.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the one of the following:-

1. Bootstrap - https://getbootstrap.com/
   This will give you a row-column layout of 12 grids. It is just a css file. You can manipulate your look for different screens simply using css classes.
2. Media Queries -[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)